# Should I use a hyphen in the term "in(-)situ visualization"?

Tags: orthography, hyphenation

The term *in(-)situ visualization* denotes a visualization or graphics that is depicted in place, for instance, a [sparkline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparkline) that is embedded into text.

As the dictionaries tell, the adjective or adverb *in situ* is written as two words. But for concatenated terms in scientific language, oftentimes, *in-situ* (with a hyphen) is placed in front of the main noun. Searching for the term in Google and Google Scholar, I find both alternatives about equally frequent. Also, the [COCA Corpus](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) lists both versions for related terms such as *in(-)situ burning*.

What is the correct spelling of *in(-)situ visualization*? Is there a specific rule that applies?

Comment: No hyphen needed. It is a foreign phrase (?'borrowed phrase') with a specific meaning. The same form of the phrase can be used for all purposes. Use of the hyphen is a scholarly hypercorrection, I believe.

Comment: You should write *visualization in situ* as if it were Latin and/or English rather than, say, German.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No hyphen needed.

***[In situ](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/in-situ?q=in%20situ)*** (*adverb & adjective*)  is a Latin phrase (?'borrowed phrase') with a specific meaning. The same form of the phrase can be used for all purposes.

Use of the hyphen is a scholarly hypercorrection, I believe.

Comment: Why "scholarly"?  Wouldn't scholars be less likely to indulge in hypercorrection than the unschooled?  The practice is by definition associated with thinking one knows more than one actually does.

Comment: The scholars typically aren't trained in English language but in other disciplines.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with the lengthy reply provided by @dodgethesteamroller that ended with "Thus "in situ visualization" is unambiguous because "in situ" cannot be mistaken for two separate adjectives; there is no such thing as "situ visualization." It's fine to put the hyphen in, but it may be perceived as old-fashioned by some copyeditors."

However, I would take it one step further to drive home the importance of the rule that usage be guided by "meaning clarification". Here's a simple rule:  "If italicizing, then no hyphen. If not italicizing, then hyphenate." Either method avoids confusion in phrases like “in in vitro experiments”  The double "in in" is not uncommon in scientific writing. Using both italics and hyphen is overkill and a good example of hypercorrection.

Answer (score 2):

My PhD is in English, but I spend a lot of time providing writing support for PhD scientists at universities and national laboratories. The case of *in situ* was one of the first real grammatical conundrums that I encountered, and I was boggled by the sheer variety of published permutations. (One well-respected scientist told me very seriously that the phrase should be either italicized or hyphenated, but not both. This was apparently advice that she had received from her graduate advisor.)

I understand the theory, but English is a continually-evolving language. (If enough people use a phrase "incorrectly" then it eventually becomes "correct" by popular consensus.) Realistically, there are different grammatical trends that have emerged within certain scientific sub-fields.

My practical advice to scientists who want to publish in a particular journal is to go to the journal's website, do a quick search for "in situ," and see how the journal prefers to punctuate the phrase (as an adjective and as an adverb). If the journal is consistent, follow the preferences of the journal. If the journal is inconsistent, then you have room to choose, as long as your paper is internally consistent.

Comment: Hello, 388. Perfectly sound advice, but about the hundredth repeat.

Answer (score 1):

The key here is not whether or not *in situ* is properly spelled as two words (it is) nor what its part of speech is (it can be an adjective or adverb).  The question is whether it should be hyphenated when used as an adjective directly before a noun.  You're not finding an explanation in the dictionary simply because it's a matter more appropriate to a style or usage handbook.

Hyphens in compound adjectives, up until the latter part of the twentieth century, were considered mandatory.  Modern usage, however, is to use them only to clarify meaning.  Sometimes the need for such clarification is quite subtle:

- Wikipedia gives an excellent example of "white-hot metal" vs. "white
  hot metal."  In the former, "white-hot" is a particular state of the
  heating of the metal; it describes metal heated to the point where it
  turns white.  In the latter, "white" and "hot" are given equal weight
  when describing the metal; it is white, and it is hot, but the former
  word is not semantically modifying the latter.
- Homer's *Odyssey* contains a noun phrase famously translated as "wine-dark seas."  Here the hyphen is necessary because "wine" alone cannot be an adjective, but in combination with "seas" alone it could conceivably be taken as a noun phrase with a different meaning: "wine seas" could be a slightly strange way to refer to "vast quantities of wine."  But this is not what the poet and the translator meant: rather, "wine-dark" is an adjective invented especially for the situation, a compound meaning "as dark as wine."  (I was taught in grade school to interpret such expressions as answering questions from the inside out: What is being described? *Seas.* What kind of seas where they? *Dark seas.* What kind of dark seas? *Wine-dark seas, as dark as wine.*)

Thus "*in situ* visualization" is unambiguous because "in situ" cannot be mistaken for two separate adjectives; there is no such thing as "situ visualization."  It's fine to put the hyphen in, but it may be perceived as old-fashioned by some copyeditors.

Comment: Except that "in situ" is *not* a compound adjective, but rather a Latin prepositional phrase being used as an adjective, just like "in vitro" and "in utero," which I have also never, for the life of me, seen hyphenated.

Comment: @BranimirĆaćić According to the definition of "compound adjective" given [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_modifier#Compound_adjectives), it's both.  And Google will show you plenty of examples of "in-vitro" and "in-utero" before nouns.

Comment: "Thus 'in situ visualization' is unambiguous because 'in situ' cannot be mistaken for two separate adjectives; there is no such thing as 'situ visualization.'" It is unambiguous *if* the reader is familiar with the relatively uncommon term *in situ*. If not, "situ visualization" may seem to be the more appropriate reading in many contexts, which would send the reader on a wild goose chase for a definition that doesn't exist. I would use the hyphen.

Comment: @phenry Very good point, and one that people who advocate for no hyphen, in the modern style, would do well to consider!

Comment: First time I've had an answer of mine simultaneously accepted as correct and downvoted below zero.  I don't know what to make of that...

Comment: @phenry It has been the custom to italicize foreign words: "*in situ* visualization" -- that too helps recognize the phrase as a unit.

Answer (score 0):

This is the type of question that can easily be answered by referring to a *dictionary*. *Dictionaries* are much better than search engines for this type of question. Search engines only tell you what is there, i.e. what others have used - be it right or wrong. Dictionaries tell you what is right.

[Chambers](http://www.chambers.co.uk/search.php?query=insitu&title=21st) and [ODO (Oxford)](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/in-situ?q=insitu) both give "in situ" (*two* words) for use as adjectives or adverbs, in British usage. American usage may differ - use an American dictionary if that is what you require.

#### [Following added after Question was modified]

Personally, I see no problem with hyphenating *in-situ* when used as an adjective or adverb, and indeed, it may be considered as making it clearer. It is not unusual to hyphenate compound adjectives: whether or not to is more a matter of style, clarity, and common usage. It is not really a matter of which is right or wrong.

But, "in situ" is two words and I think it may be considered incorrect to write it as one un-hyphenated word. I certainly wouldn't do so.

Comment: This is true, the dictionaries list _in situ_ (without a hyphen) as an adjective/adverb, also the American ones. But still, as Google Scholar and the COCA corpus confirm, it is frequently used with a hyphen in front of nouns for established terms in scientific language. So, why? Is there any rule that applies or is it just an error? I did not find the answer in the dictionary.

Comment: I extended the question with respect to what dictionaries tell.

Comment: And I've extended the answer!

Comment: Hello! Welcome back! Good to see you again, it's been a long time :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA what do you think about the rollback that just occured?

Comment: @NikeDattani what about it? The user who rolled back the edit is the author, they didn't like it, it's their prerogative. You win some and you lose some.

Comment: It's not their "prerogative" since absolutely anyone with enough rep can rollback, not just the author, but I get your point. I just thought it was weird that someone would rollback to a version with poorer grammar. In fact unnecessary editing of ones own post can be seen as an abuse of the system since it bumps the post to the top of the front page and can be a way to attract more votes. Luckily that didn't happen here.

Answer (score 0):

An interesting test could be to replace the Latin phrase with its English equivalent: "in position." Using the common test of decomposing the phrase from right to left on the phrase "in situ visualization," try "in position visualization." The phrase "position visualization" may not make sense to the reader, causing the to try to interpret "in position visualization" with "in position" combined, as if it did have a hyphen. Hyphenating the phrase ("in-position visualization") seems preferable here. I agree with @phenry that using a hyphen will only help the reader avoid a double-take on the phrase, especially if they are unfamiliar with the Latin phrase.