# Is the usage of a hyphen in "ad hoc" acceptable?

Tags: punctuation, hyphenation, latin, compound-adjectives

I know that "ad hoc" is a Latin phrase and I've typically seen it used without a hyphen. However, many technical articles use a hyphen. For example:

> Ad-hoc mode is useful for establishing a network where wireless infrastructure does not exist or where services are not required.

(http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/A/ad_hoc_mode.html)

Is "ad hoc" always the correct usage? If it can be "ad-hoc", is the usage of the hyphen specific to certain circumstances?

Comment: Multi-word modifiers before a noun are usually hyphenated in English, like _a ten-year-old boy._

Comment: The hyphenation appears to be inconsistent even when "ad hoc" is used as an adjective. E.g.: http://www.logianalytics.com/bi-encyclopedia/ad-hoc-reporting; http://www.activereportsserver.com/ad-hoc-reporting

Comment: For reference when citing a link, it's good to paste in at least part of the relevant quote in case the link goes dead in time.

Comment: I have seen it more frequently in technical articles without the hyphen. As BraddSzonye points out, one may choose to hyphenate it when it is a modifier before a noun. As Kristina Lopez points out, one may choose to never hyphenate it.

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Comment: Yes, it's 'acceptable," unless you want to burn at the stake anybody who deviates a little from what others consider an iron clad rule. Iron-clad?

Comment: Related: [Should I use a hyphen in the term “in(-)situ visualization”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/118089)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The rule-of-thumb I've found in researching this issue, (though no reference to a specific style guide was referenced – one site linked [here](http://www.stc-techedit.org/tiki-view_forum_thread.php?comments_offset=0&comments_threadId=0&comments_parentId=1163&comments_threshold=0&thread_sort_mode=commentDate_desc&topics_offset=346&topics_find=&topics_sort_mode=replies_asc&topics_threshold=0&forumId=4&time_control=86400&display=print)) is if Latin and other foreign phrases are **not** hyphenated in their original language, then they are **not** hyphenated in English.

Comment: The rule of thumb seemes true to some degree, but see the notes to the other answers.  However, your use of hyphens in your answer is certainly incorrect, as "rule of thumb" is not functioning as an adjective.

Comment: @BobRhodes The rule of thumb mentioned is a recommendation given in a dated version of a style guide; I don't see how it can '[seem] true [I'd say 'reasonable'] to some degree' based solely on this information.

Comment: I'd endorse the rule of thumb. For compound premodifiers in general, the rationale is usually 'hyphenate where (and only where) not to do so creates ambiguity or other problems'. So 'a slowly turning spit', 'three hundred year-old trees', 'three hundred-year-old trees','three-hundred-year-old trees','a died-in-the-wool Tory'. The terms 'ad hoc' and 'a priori' are unlikely to lead to confusion amongst those familiar with them. Of course, breaking a rule of thumb isn't a hanging offence.

Answer (score 2):

"ad-hoc" is wrong; "ad hoc" is correct. The book *[Grammatically Correct](http://books.google.com/books?id=PEHLt67UewYC&lpg=PA27&dq=hyphenate%20ad%20hoc&pg=PA27#v=onepage&q=hyphenate%20ad%20hoc&f=false)* (2nd edition) by Anne Stilman mentions this as a commonly mis-hyphenated compound, along with the following (correct usages):

- more or less
- ongoing
- under way
- a priori
- bona fide
- post hoc
- vice versa

The same book provides further guidance on hyphenation, a good reference.

Comment: Who the h3ll is Anne Stilman and why should I believe her(/him)?