# In situ formation or in-situ formation?

Tags: hyphenation, latin

I am using the following phrase in an abstract I'm writing:

> in situ formation of planets

I wanted to ask if a hyphen is needed in this phrase, and if so where?

[This question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/118089/should-i-use-a-hyphen-in-the-term-in-situ-visualization) says that "in situ" should not be hyphenated because the two words are not two separate adjectives, but rather "in situ" is a single adjective, borrowed from Latin.  I wanted to confirm that this analysis carries over to this particular usage of "in situ".

Comment: Since it is Latin, my preference would be to see it italicized, not hyphenated. Unrelated aside: Where else do planets form, other than *in situ*?

Comment: @MarkHubbard, they can form further out from a star and then later migrate inward to an orbit closer to the star than where they originally formed.  It's also possible for stars to capture planets from other stars during particularly close encounters.

Comment: This is general reference. [Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/in_situ) has examples: **in situ** ADJECTIVE & ADVERB 1 In the original place.
[AS ADVERB] ‘frescoes have been left in situ’
[AS ADJECTIVE] ‘a collection of in situ pumping engines’

1.1 In the appropriate position.
[AS ADVERB] ‘her guests were all in situ’ / This is not to say that other authorities would not prefer a hyphen for the compound when used prenominally, but is a readily available correct answer.

Comment: Wikipedia states, "*In situ* (/ɪn ˈsɪtjuː/ or /ɪn ˈsaɪtʃuː/; often not italicized in English[1][2][3]) is a Latin phrase that translates literally to "on site"[4] or "in position".[5] It means "locally", "on site", "on the premises" or "in place" to describe an event where it takes place, and is used in many different contexts." Wikipedia then proceeds to italicize *in situ* throughout the remainder of the article.

Comment: Wikipedia is out of date here, and 'is a Latin phrase' is disingenuous. Almost as bad as saying '_Anatomy_ is a Latin word'.

Comment: @Joshua - Thank you for the explanation regarding formation of planets. I appreciate it.

Comment: @DocG., I reference that question in my question.  I wanted to make sure the same rules still applied over to my usage, which at the time I wrote the question seemed different.